# Явное приведение типов C++

Tags: c++

Какая разница между двумя последними строками? И если в этом примере ее нет, то бывает ли она вообще?

```
int n=9;
double a=double(n);
double b=(double)n;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разницы никакой нет, можете добавить ещё

```
double b=static_cast<double>(n);
```

в копилку, для полноты картины. Правда это немного сбиавает с толку, т.к. "приведение типов" зачастую превращается в создание другого типа, без использования явных операторов приведения, а за счёт конструктора. Как бы запутанно это не было, 3 различных синтаксиса дают одно и то же в результате(правда static_cast "умнее", но это к делу не относится)

Также рекомендую к прочтению Item 27 в книге Скотта Мэйерса "Effective C++, Third Edition". Эта книга есть на русском языке.

Comment: Я вспомнил пример с long long.

Comment: Скажу больше. В данном случае все точно так же работает и *без явного* приведения типа. `int n; double d = n;` / Подобные правила преобразования между числовыми типами  встроены в компилятор.

Answer (score 3):

(type) expr — форма преобразования, которая была в C.
type(expr) — появилась в C++.
В плюсах допустимы оба варианта, первый оставлен для совместимости, да и только.

Comment: есть ли какая-то разница между ними с точки зрения памяти?

Comment: Разницы нет ни какой. Один из примеров в стандарте n4296, страница 273-274, § 12.3.2. ( https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard )

Answer (score 2):

В конкретном примере разницы нет.

В общем случае бывает. Первая конструкция вызывает конструктор, передав ему соответствующие параметры, а вторая - это непосредственно операция приведения типа.

<strike>Разница будет (если не ошибаюсь) с explicit-конструкторами и, возможно, с перегруженными операторами приведения.</strike>

Что-то я уже не уверен в том, что сказал про разницу. Лучше подождать других ответов. Но про синтаксический смысл конструкций всё верно.

Я вспомнил пример, где были проблемы с приведением. Некоторое время назад gcc не мог съесть такое (не знаю, научился ли сейчас):

```
long long x = long long(smth);
```

а так всё было нормально:

```
long long x = (long long)smth;
```

VS понимала оба варианта.

Comment: может так?) (long long)(smth);

Comment: @Alex, во-первых, зачем мудрить, а во-вторых, мне кажется или эта конструкция имеет тот же синтаксис, что и вторая, а не первая?